# Mecanica de cañerias para un FLappy Bird

Tags: godot-engine

Soy un nuevo programador que se quiere enfocar en los videojuegos y estoy recreando un Flappy Bird para practicar. Todo iba muy bien hasta que intente crear la mecánica de las cañerías, estas tienen que aparecer en un lugar aleatorio e ir avanzando a medida que el juego pase. Tengo un código que hice con ayuda de Chat GPT pero este me tira un error y no se como solucionarlo. Me encantaría recibir ayuda y consejos para mejorar el código de la mecánica. Muchas gracias.

Lenguaje: GDscript
Motor: Godot

Explicacion de nodos: Tengo un Nodo2D como nodo principal, dentro de este tengo un nodo Sprite2D para la textura de las cañerias y un nodo Timer. En el nodo Timer tengo una señal conectada al Script del Nodo2d, esta se llama _on_pipe_timer_timeout()

Codigo

```
extends Node2D

const PIPE_GAP = 200
const PIPE_SPEED = 100

# Declara la variable pipe_timer y asigna un nuevo nodo Timer
@onready var pipe_timer = $Timer

# Utiliza la notación de señales para conectar la señal timeout del temporizador a la función _on_pipe_timer_timeout
func _ready():
    # Configurar el temporizador para generar cañerías cada cierto tiempo
    pipe_timer.wait_time = 2
    pipe_timer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_pipe_timer_timeout")

func _on_pipe_timer_timeout():
    # Generar una nueva pareja de cañerías
    var pipe_top = Sprite2D.new()
    var pipe_bottom = Sprite2D.new()

# Configurar las texturas de las cañerías (puedes usar tus propias texturas)
    pipe_top.texture = load("res://Recursos/Pipe/pipe-green.png")
    pipe_bottom.texture = load("res://Recursos/Pipe/pipe-green.png")

    # Calcular la posición vertical aleatoria para la cañería superior
    var random_y = randf_range(100, get_viewport_rect().size.y - PIPE_GAP - 100)

    # Posicionar las cañerías
    pipe_top.position.y = random_y - PIPE_GAP / 2
    pipe_bottom.position.y = random_y + PIPE_GAP / 2

    # Agregar las cañerías como nodos hijos
    add_child(pipe_top)
    add_child(pipe_bottom)

# Mueve y elimina las cañerías
func _process(delta):
    # Mover las cañerías hacia la izquierda
    for child in get_children():
        child.position.x -= PIPE_SPEED * delta

        # Eliminar las cañerías que salen completamente de la pantalla
        if child.position.x < -100:
            child.queue_free()
```

Linea del error: pipe_timer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_pipe_timer_timeout")

Tipo de errores
Línea 13:Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 2 should be "Callable" but is "res://Codigo/Pipe.gd".
Línea 13:Cannot pass a value of type "String" as "int".
Línea 13:Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 3 should be "int" but is "String".

Ya probe cambiando el codigo de mil maneras y no logro conseguir esa mecanica, me gustaria que alguien pueda arreglarme el codigo o darme sugerencias para cambiarlo

Comment: Par que puedan ayudarte deberias hacer un recorrido por el sitio y revisar como [hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Debes formatear el código que mustras, y debes dar más detalles. No pretendas que aquí te soluciones los problemas. Dices que eres un nuevo programador, pero el código lo has creado con Chat GPT. Quizá deberias aprender a programar,  o deberias preguntarle a GPT porque que te da errores. Muestra algo claroy podran ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Si como supongo estas usando Godot 4, estamos ante otro ejemplo más de una IA que vomita código sin tener en cuenta que hay que actualizarse... Esa forma de conectar señales:

```
pipe_timer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_pipe_timer_timeout")
```

es la que se usa en Godot 3, en Godot 4 las señales son objetos de primera clase y la sintaxis general es algo así:

```
nodo.señal.connect(callback)
```

En tu caso debería ser:

```
pipe_timer.timeout.connect(_on_pipe_timer_timeout)
```

Las funciones (callables) también son ahora "objetos de primera clase", por lo que se pueden pasar directamente como argumento a otra función, en vez de usar una cadena con su nombre como se hacía anteriormente.